# Why is the skinned mesh renderer invisible / not rendering on play (neither in scene or game view)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Screenshots of the issue:

[Mesh is visible before hitting play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbpWz.jpg)

[Mesh is not visible after hitting play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qwxf.jpg)

I'm using Unity version 2019.4.18f1 and have noticed this issue ever since switching out my generic capsule player model for [this free rigged model from Royal Skies](https://www.theroyalskies.com/royal-resources)(I did modify and re-export an .fbx file after adding animations in Blender) and setting up the animations. When I hit play the model stops rendering in both the scene and game view.

If I remove the model from the avatar slot in the animator then I don't have the issue so I'm assuming it has to do with the animations but I haven't been able to find any good solutions anywhere online where people have had the same issue. The closest post I've seen with similar issues is [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/995tqn/skinned_mesh_renderer_invisible/) but none mention the animations/animator.

Here's some of my code:

Handling the animation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    int horizontal;
    int vertical;
    private void Awake()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        horizontal = Animator.StringToHash("Horizontal");
        vertical = Animator.StringToHash("Vertical");
    }
    public void UpdateAnimatorValues(float horizontalMovement, float verticalMovement)
    {
        animator.SetFloat(horizontal, horizontalMovement, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        animator.SetFloat(vertical, verticalMovement, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Handling the movement

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    AnimManager animManager;

    public PlayerInput inputActions;
    public GameObject rotator;
    public GameObject player;
    public Transform rotationTarget;
    public Transform frontTarget;
    public Transform rearTarget;
    public Transform playerModel;

    public float movementX;
    //private float moveAmount;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
    public float jumpHeight = 100f;

    private Rigidbody pbody;
    private CharacterController pCont;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputActions = new PlayerInput();
        inputActions.PlayerMovement.Jump.performed += context => OnJump();
        pbody = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pCont = player.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        animManager = GetComponent<AnimManager>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //moving the character
        movementX = inputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.ReadValue<float>();
        rotator.transform.Rotate(0, movementX * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        animManager.UpdateAnimatorValues(0, movementX);

        //face targets
        if (movementX < 0)
        {
            var newTarget = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, frontTarget.position, 2f);
            playerModel.LookAt(newTarget);
        }
        if (movementX > 0)
        {
            playerModel.LookAt(rearTarget);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputActions.PlayerMovement.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputActions.PlayerMovement.Disable();
    }
    private void OnJump()
    {
        Debug.Log("jump");
        pbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0));
    }

}
```

Thanks. Every suggestion helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is, as you suggested yourself, probably an error with the animation setup.

I importer Unity's old [Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2018-4-32351) and used its third-person controller on the model and it works fine (well, depreciated package and some animations missing, but nothing wrong with the model).

[image: Example of the third-person character with the model]

Comment: Thanks Anders. I'm still new to animation so I guess I just need to figure out how to apply it properly.